# Extract time portion out of Timestamp

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I am using [Azure Application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference) and would like to extract just the time portion out of Timestamp.

For ex:

```
   Input : "2017-01-23T20:00:00.2804261Z"; //This is a Timestamp data type
   Output : 20:00:00.2804261Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract day from the existing timestamp to leave only the "time" part of it:

```
QueryHere
| extend date_output = floor(timestamp, 1d)
| extend time_output = timestamp - date_output
```

The output will be something like

```
Timestamp: "2017-01-23T20:00:00.2804261Z"
date_output: "2017-01-23T00:00:00.0000000Z"
time_output: "20:00:00.2804261"
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. That worked great.  substring(tostring(timestamp),11) also seems to work

Comment: You can also use modulo on 1 day to get the time part: | extend time_output = timestamp % 1d